# Cooldown handler - discord.js. How can i remove cooldown inside command script

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm building a cooldown 'handler' for commands for my discord bot. It works but have some issues. When someone for example type write wrong argument or doesn't write anything for my command it will still fire cooldown. I need a way to somehow remove that cooldown in my script or some other way. Also I can't check just for arguments for example if there is a word or number, because I sometimes need to check some values in my database. I would like to have cooldown removal in script in the command.

```
const { prefix: defaultPrefix } = require("../../config");
const prefixSchema = require("../../models/prefixSchema");

const languageSchema = require('../../models/languageSchema');
const { translations } = require("../../lang.json");

const discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {

  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') return;

  let prefix;
  let dbPrefix = await prefixSchema.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id });

  if (dbPrefix) {
    prefix = dbPrefix.prefix;
  } else {
    prefix = defaultPrefix;
  }
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(cmd) ||
    client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

  const jezyk = await languageSchema.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id,
  })

  const lang = jezyk.language

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new discord.Collection());
  }

  const current_time = Date.now();
  const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

  if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

    if (current_time < expiration_time) {
      //const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
      const time_left = new Date(expiration_time - current_time).toISOString().substr(11, 8)

      const bicon = client.user.displayAvatarURL();
      const cooldown_command = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${translations.ERROR_OCCUR[lang]}`, client.user.avatarURL())
        .setDescription(`${translations.TIMEOUT_DESCRIPTION_1[lang]} **${time_left}** ${translations.TIMEOUT_DESCRIPTION_2[lang]} **${command.name}**!`)
        .setColor(`#FF6347`)
        .setFooter(`${translations.DATE[lang]}`)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(cooldown_command);
    }
  }

  time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
  setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

  try {
    if (command) command.execute(message, args, client);
  } catch (err) {
    message.reply("wystąpił błąd krytyczny!");
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t the most efficient solution, but if you put `return 'success'`, or something *unique* that you wouldn’t return for anything else except for completion, at the **bottom** of every command file

```js
try {
    if (command) var complete =
await command.execute(message, args, client);
  } catch (err) {
    message.reply("wystąpił błąd krytyczny!");
    console.log(err);
  }
//BEFORE COOLDOWN SETTING!
if(complete !== 'success') return;
//set cooldown here
```